# fusionchart when one value is more than 1000

Tags: xml, fusioncharts

```
<chart caption="Forecast vs Actual"     
   subcaption="Forecast category : Nag In ( Forecast Period :Jan 31, 2013) "    
       lineThickness="0"                                    
       showBorder="0"                                   
      showValues="0"    
  formatNumberScale="0" 
  anchorRadius="2"              
  divLineAlpha="20"
  divLineColor="CC3300"                         
      divLineIsDashed="1"   
  showAlternateHGridColor="1"   
  alternateHGridAlpha="5"
  alternateHGridColor="CC3300"  
  labelStep="1" 
  numvdivlines="12"
      chartRightMargin="75" 
  chartLeftMargin="80"  
  slantLabels ="1"
  labelDisplay='Rotate' 
      bgColor="FFFFFF"> 
<categories>  
<category 
    label="Jan 16, 2013 07 42 27 AM"  />
<category label="Jan 11, 2013 08 42 04 AM"  />  
</categories> 
<dataset 
  seriesName="Forecast Amount (%)"  
  color="1D8BD1"    
  anchorBorderColor="1D8BD1"
  anchorBgColor="1D8BD1"> 
 <set value="1,440.00"/>
 <set value="1,360.00"/>
</dataset> 
<dataset seriesName="Actual Amount (%)"
  color="F1683C"    
  anchorBorderColor="F1683C" 
  anchorBgColor="F1683C"> 
  <set value="100.00"/>
 <set value="100.00"/>
</dataset> 
<dataset seriesName="Variance Amount (%)" 
 color="DF0174" 
 anchorBorderColor="DF0174" 
     anchorBgColor="DF0174"> 
     <set value="93.06"/>
     <set value="92.65"/>
 </dataset> 
</chart>
```

I have this XML. I am not able to see Forecast Amount in graph. I am using following code in javascript function:

```
   var FVSAChart3 = new FusionCharts("lib/charts/MSLine.swf", "byEntityGraph", "750", "480", "0", "0");
    FVSAChart3.setDataURL("AccGraph.xml");
    FVSAChart3.render("forecast-vs-actuals-entity");
```

Please give any suggestions. I think problem is forecast amount value is more than 1000 if that is less than 1000 it is working fine.. and I am using version 1.2.

Comment: Please try and format that XML reasonably. There's a help button in the editor, please mark the formatted XML as a code block.

Comment: To add to @Sanjukta Mukherjee 's answer: Ideally you need to pass un-formatted (without decimals separator, currency, prefix, suffix etc.) values in your XML. The chart can automatically show formatted values with decimals separator etc. Hence, instead of 1,440.00, please provide 1440.00 (yes decimal separator is part of a number an not part of formatting). In case, you are forced to pass formatted values, you need to use inThousanSeparator (incoming thousands separator character) attribute to help the chart understand that in your value there exist thousand separator characters.

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting the "," as the value for the "inThousandSeparator" attribute in the  element of the XML.

```
<chart ... inThousandSeparator=','>
```

In this case you would be able to use the XML data that you had previously posted and your chart would be displayed perfectly.

When you provide any custom values with "," or "." as thousand or decimal separators, you would need to use "inThousandSeparator" or "inDecimalSeparator" in the  element of the XML.